# Regex - How to reject based on string length?

Tags: regex

Regex:

```
^[U][S][A]\d{2}[C][S]\d{3}
```

It indicates these values are valid:

```
USA25CS131 (valid)
USA25CS1311 (invalid length)
```

How do I get it to reject a string that's too long?

Comment: `[U]` is equal to `U`. So either have `[USA]{3}` which can be anything from `SSS` to `UUU` or just type `USA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply anchor the regex at the end with `$`, like this:

```
^[U][S][A]\d{2}[C][S]\d{3}$
```

and now you won't match strings with extra characters at the end.

You can also simplify your regex to this:

```
^USA\d{2}CS\d{3}$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^\w{1,10}$
```

That will match on anything 1-10 characters long, ^ means start of the line and $ means end of the line. You can adapt this with your code to produce the results you want.

Given your specific regex I would use `^[U][S][A]\d{2}[C][S]\d{3}$`(just adding $ to the end)